# Filtering SharePoint List columns using a textbox (like filters in MS Excel)

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, filter

I want to enable search on every column of a SharePoint List.
It should work like filtering in Excel. User can type in the textbox and filter that column.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't too difficult to create a Calculated Column which adds a KeyUp eventlistner to the existing Searchbox in a view; enabling filtering of items.

This does **not** create a searchbox above all columns.

[image]

Since the magic is in a Calculated Column **for every listitem** it is very easy to add filtering for additional Columns

detailed steps at:
http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/SearchFilter

Comment: Love the `.gif`!

Comment: Easy animated GIF  creation with http://blog.gyazo.com/2013/10/gyazo-version-20-adds-gif-and-video.html